# Select 50 random files per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to select 50 random files per day since October 1st, 2012.
For example:

- October 1st = 50 files
- October 2nd = 50 files
- October 3rd = 50 files
- Etc.....today

So far I can select 1 file per day, but I need 50. And I needed them to be random

```
DECLARE @DaysBack AS INT
SET @DaysBack = -25


    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT FileDate, MAX(FileName)  FROM (
    SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(second,actiondate, CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime)), 101) AS FileDate

    ,'\\directory\' + filename AS FileName
    FROM   Tableq q
    JOIN tablec c
    on  q.projectid = c.projectid
           AND actiondate >= Datediff(s, '19700101 00:00:00:000',
                             Dateadd(DAY, @DaysBack, Getutcdate()))


    ) x

    GROUP BY FileDate
    ORDER  BY FileDate
```

Comment: Can you post your table schema and maybe some example data?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have access to a SQL Server instance (or SQL Fiddle) at present.  But this should give a random id per actiondate...

- `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY actiondate ORDER BY NEWID())`

This would mean that the following will pick a random 50 items per actiondate...

```
DECLARE @DaysBack AS INT
SET @DaysBack = -25

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT
  FileDate, FileName
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, actiondate / 86400, '19700101') AS FileDate,
    '\\\\directory\\' + filename AS FileName,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY actiondate / 86400 ORDER BY NEWID()) AS random_daily_id
FROM
  Tableq q
JOIN
  tablec c
    ON  q.projectid = c.projectid
    AND actiondate >= Datediff(s, '19700101', Dateadd(DAY, @DaysBack, Getutcdate()))
) x
WHERE
  random_daily_id <= 50
ORDER BY
  FileDate
```

Comment: You are almost there, but it gives me more than 50 rows per day. Actually its giving me almost 99% of the rows back

Comment: I guess, therefor that `actiondate` isn't actually a date? It includes the time component during the day as well?  *[Code editted to partition by Days.]*

Comment: You are correct, Actiondate is a unix time stamp. That is why I convert it to date. Yes it includes the time....

Comment: @Dems - I saw you elsewhere mention that you were stuck with IE7, and for that reason couldn't use SQL Fiddle. However, I just checked the site with IE10 using IE7 compat mode, and it seems to work fine. Could you email some details about what's not working for you? admin at sqlfiddle dot com - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use ranking functions to do this:

```
SELECT FileDate, MAX(FileName)
FROM (select x.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by FileDate order by newid()) as seqnum
      from (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(second,actiondate, CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime)), 101
                          ) AS FileDate,
                   '\\directory\' + filename AS FileName
            FROM   Tableq q JOIN
                   tablec c
                   on  q.projectid = c.projectid and
                       actiondate >= Datediff(s, '19700101 00:00:00:000',
                                     Dateadd(DAY, @DaysBack, Getutcdate()))
           ) x
     ) x
where seqnum <= 50
ORDER  BY FileDate
```

This uses `row_number()` to add a sequence number for the files on each date, with the number assigned randomly.  It then chooses the top 50 for each date.

Answer (score 0):

I **warmly** suggest you not to implement any random extraction db side. I had a similar requirement in a project, but eventually I moved the randomizing logic to the business side.

Comment: So, if you have 1,000,000 records and you want a random sample of 1,000 records you *really* pull all 1,000,000 and then downsample?

Comment: @Dems. Each problem with its context. It is a suggestion. And, anyway, what's the matter in processing 1 milion integer keys (you don't want to recover all the records fields in order to randomize, don't you)?